# Sending JWT token in the headers with Postman

Tags: express, jwt, postman

I'm testing an implementation of JWT Token based security based off the following [article](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/). I have successfully received a token from the test server. I can't figure out how to have the Chrome POSTMAN REST Client program send the token in the header.

[image: postman screenshot]

My questions are as follows:

1) Am I using the right header name and/or POSTMAN interface?

2) Do I need to base 64 encode the token? I thought I could just send the token back.

Comment: Hi, where can I see in POSTMAN the jwt token I've received?

Comment: @MLondei, it depends on the way the receiving server is configured. It can come back as a URL (find it in the URL string) or it can come back in the response body (find it in the response's body field). Those are the two major ones I'm aware of.

Comment: linkrot. new link: https://auth0.com/docs/design/web-apps-vs-web-apis-cookies-vs-tokens

Answer (score 328, accepted):

For the request Header name just use Authorization. 
Place Bearer before the Token. I just tried it out and it works for me.

Authorization:  Bearer TOKEN_STRING

Each part of the JWT is a base64url encoded value.

Comment: Just as a clarification, the "Header" field becomes Authorization and the "Value" field becomes Bearer[WHITESPACE]<your-code-here>

Comment: Do you know what part of the field is encrypted? It appears that the data right after the last '.' separator is giving me what looks like garbage characters. I assume this is actually information encrypted by the Token generator?

Comment: Check out http://jwt.io/ .There is a section where you can paste a JWT and view its decoded contents, its the best way of seeing whats happening. The server secret string is used to make the last section of the token. JWT only signs the payload does not encrypt i.e. you can decode part 1 & 2 of the string but cannot validate it without the secret. http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html

Comment: EXAMPLE. JWT secret = 'This is the secret hush hush!'                   
, Client (sends credentials via http):username and password,   
Server sends token in http response header: {"token":"
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.
eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNTNjM2E2ZGIxMmFiZmE4MDBjNTRhNDQ2IiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImFkbWluIjp0cnVlLCJjcmVhdGVkIjoiMjAxNC0wNy0xNFQwOTo0NjowMy45NTZaIiwiZW1haWwiOiJtaWNrQDEyMy5pZSIsImlhdCI6MTQwNTMzMTIwNywiZXhwIjoxNDA1MzM0ODA3fQ.
LfE_1suABLnAY8IGWd_sOWw1ONVf7KbKGrnJlGbaTsQ"}

Comment: Can someone please elaborate on why we need to put Bearer before the JWT? Is this some kind of signal to the server that this is a JWT?

Comment: That is just the convention - you can find all details here:  https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: hmm I'm doing this, but I get a `403 Forbidden` in my .net core api

Comment: why should i use `Bearer`,is it mandatory to use that name,can i use `ABC<space><token>`

Answer (score 152):

Here is an image if it helps :)

[image: Postman]

**Update:**

The postman team added "Bearer token" to the "authorization tab": 
[image: Updated postman]

Comment: How can I make it outfill the value with the latest JWT token?

Answer (score 43):

I am adding to this question a little interesting tip that may help you guys testing JWT Apis.

Its is very simple actually.

When you log in, in your Api (login endpoint), you will immediately receive your token, and as @mick-cullen said you will have to use the JWT on your header as:

```
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_STRING
```

Now if you like to automate or just make your life easier, your tests you can save the token as a global that you can call on all other endpoints as:

```
Authorization: Bearer {{jwt_token}}
```

On Postman:
Then make a Global variable in postman as jwt_token = TOKEN_STRING.

On your login endpoint:
To make it useful, add on the beginning of the Tests Tab add:

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.clearGlobalVariable("jwt_token");
postman.setGlobalVariable("jwt_token", data.jwt_token);
```

I am guessing that your api is returning the token as a json on the response as:
{"jwt_token":"TOKEN_STRING"}, there may be some sort of variation.

On the first line you add the response to the data varibale.
Clean your Global
And assign the value.

So now you have your token on the global variable, what makes easy to use           Authorization: Bearer {{jwt_token}} on all your endpoints.

Hope this tip helps.

---

EDIT
Something to read

About tests on Postman: [testing examples](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/testing_examples)

Command Line: [Newman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro)

CI: [integrating with Jenkins](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/integrating_with_jenkins)

Nice blog post: [master api test automation](http://blog.testproject.io/2016/06/22/master-api-test-automation)

Comment: Interesting, I'm unfamiliar with the concept of the `Test` tab and Postman coding. Is there a resource you recommend to get started with this?

Comment: Yup, there are some that I found useful:  

* https://www.getpostman.com/docs/testing_examples  

* http://blog.testproject.io/2016/06/22/master-api-test-automation/  

* http://www.sm-cloud.com/testing-api-with-postman/

Comment: Actually Postman is really interesting and pretty strong when it comes to automated testing.
You can configure postman in such a way that it can build random data Global variables or Environment variables that you can run on the tests. And make iterative runs and test any response as endpoint unit tests. Save them and find errors when you change code.
I haven't used the command line utility but I understand that you can configure it to run in your ci-pipeline.

Comment: Your can read about command line here: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro

Answer (score 12):

**Here is how to set token this automatically**

On your login/auth request

[image]

Then for authenticated page

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue in `Flask` and after trying the first 2 solutions which are the same (`Authorization: Bearer <token>`), and getting this:

```
{
    "description": "Unsupported authorization type",
    "error": "Invalid JWT header",
    "status_code": 401
}
```

I managed to finally solve it by using:

```
Authorization: jwt <token>
```

Thought it might save some time to people who encounter the same thing.

Comment: I was getting `Authentication credentials were not provided` in `django` using `Bearer <token>`. solved with `jwt <token>`. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 9):

If you wish to use postman the right way is to use the headers as such

key: Authorization

value: jwt {token}

as simple as that.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open postman.
2. go to "header" field.
3. there one can see "key value"  blanks.
4. in key type "Authorization".
5. in value type "Bearer(space)your_access_token_value".

Done!

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Everything else ie. *Params, Authorization, Body, Pre-request Script, Tests* is empty, just open the **Headers** tab and add as shown in image. Its the same for GET request as well.

Answer (score 3):

For people who are using wordpress plugin [Advanced Access Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/) to open up the JWT Authentication.

The Header field should put **Authentication** instead of **Authorization**

[image]

AAM mentioned it inside their [documentation](https://aamplugin.com/help/how-to-authenticate-wordpress-user-with-jwt-token),

> Note! AAM **does not use standard Authorization header** as it is skipped 
>   by most Apache servers. ...

---

*Hope it helps someone! Thanks for other answers helped me alot too!!*

Answer (score 1):

I did as how moplin mentioned .But in my case service send the JWT in response headers ,as a value under the key "Authorization".

```
Authorization →Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJpbWFsIiwiZXhwIjoxNDk4OTIwOTEyfQ.dYEbf4x5TGr_kTtwywKPI2S-xYhsp5RIIBdOa_wl9soqaFkUUKfy73kaMAv_c-6cxTAqBwtskOfr-Gm3QI0gpQ
```

What I did was ,make a Global variable in postman as

> key->jwt
>   value->blahblah

in login request->Tests Tab, add

```
postman.clearGlobalVariable("jwt");
postman.setGlobalVariable("jwt", postman.getResponseHeader("Authorization"));
```

in other requests select the Headers tab and give

> key->Authorization
>
> value->{{jwt}}

Answer (score 1):

In Postman latest version(7++) may be there is no Bearer field in Authorization 
So go to Header tab

select key as Authorization and in value write JWT

Comment: For v7.19.0+ and it's also been there for a while, there's a `Bearer Token` helper in the `Authorization` tab, adding the token value here (Hardcoded or as a dynamic variable) will create the same `Authorization` header for the request.

Answer (score 0):

x-access-token on headers works for me.

```
key: x-access-token
value: token
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get your access token by making a call to whatever endpoint provides the token (as I assume you already did). Then you use that token in the Postman request you want to send, by adding a Header. For Postman v10.21.11:
[image: Postman headers]

Header should have "**Authorization**" as key and the value should be the string "**Bearer** " followed by the access token provided to you. Keep in mind a couple things:

- The access token consists of 3 parts separated by dots "." and you
  should include all 3 parts.
- "Bearer" needs to be just like that. Don't change capitalization.
- The token might have a very short expiration time (depending on what
  was configured for that endpoint) so you might need to obtain a new
  token quite often if that time is short.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow postman didn't work for me.
I had to use a chrome extension called RESTED which did work.