# KeyCloak User validation and getting token

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

First of all I am very new to Keycloak and excuse me if something I am asking might be wrong.

I have installed the Keycloak server and I can access the Web UI for the same using:

http://localhost:8008/auth

My requirement is to validate a realm user by passing it to k
Keycloak API and to get the token from there in response, and then pass this token for my other Web API calls.

But I was not able to find a simple guide on how I can do this...

UPDATE:

---

USING UI from `KEYCLOAK`:

So far now:

- I am able to create a `realm`:
  e.g: `DemoRealm`
- Under the `Realm` I have created the client:
  e.g: `DemoClient`
- Under the client I have created the user:
  e.g: `DemoUser`

USING `POSTMAN`:

I am also able to successfully get the token using

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/DemoRelam/protocol/openid-connect/token

POST:
{
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"username": "",
"password": "",
"client_secret":"",
"client_id":"DemoClient"
}
```

In response I am getting the token.

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsINVSHGhepnDu13SwRBL-v-y-04_6e6IJbMzreZwPI-epwdVPQe-ENhpvms2WdGM_DmgMLZ8YQFS4LDl9R7ZHT8AgXe-WCFV6OFkA7zvdeFwQ4kVVZE0HlNgHgoi4DrgMfwwz_ku1yJNJP3ztTY1nEqmA",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "refresh_expires_in": 1800,
    "refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJRRnB5YlloMGVEektIdlhOb3JvaFUxdlRvWVdjdP3vbfvk7O0zvppK9N4-oaUqZSr0smHv5LkuLDQYdPuxA",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "not-before-policy": 0,
    "session_state": "bb1c586a-e880-4b96-ac16-30e42c0f46dc"
}
```

Furthermore I was diving into more details and found this API guide:

http://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource

In this guide it's mentioned that I can get the users for the realm using
Get users Returns a list of users, filtered according to query parameters

```
GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users
```

But when I am using `POSTMAN` to get the users I am getting *403* error code. I am passing the same token as on authentication which I got in the earlier step.

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/DemoRelam/users
```

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Do you mean you just now installed the keycloak and run it while it's not integrated with we b application ? If you will see too many things avaiable over internet and keycloak documentation how to integrated keycloak with web application

Comment: @SubodhJoshi i don't want to integrate the keycloak with web application. I was to pass the user/client under relam and get the token and pass this token to some other api where again i'll validate this token

Comment: With ui it may not possible use the keycloak rest api or admin-cli .

Comment: @SubodhJoshi i have updated my question with what i achieved till now can you help me out .

Comment: I think this will help you.

have got the access token but don't know how to test this using postman. > you should just need to add the authrisation header in Postman,  
have got the access token but don't know how to test this using postman. > you should just need to add the authorization header in Postman, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709944/jwt-token-in-postman-header 

I found this see if it will help you otherwise I can write proper answer morning only right now I am using my mobile for coment.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi thank you very much i will post whether its working or not . One more question for now i am getting the token at client level can it is possible to get the token at user level

Comment: @SubodhJoshi i think its authenticating so i am not getting 401 but instead i am getting 403 error code.It seems some authorization error. I don't know for what reason i am getting this

Comment: 403 forbidden tells us that we don't have permission to see the requested resource,it's mainly due to permission . In many cases if you are using https and didn't import certificate into client it will throw 403 forbidden error.

Comment: See this will surely help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/46470477/476828

Comment: @SubodhJoshi thank you so much its working.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi One more question for now i am getting the token at client level can it is possible to get the token at user level

Comment: Here something for you.

Getting tokens over REST endpoints for regular users is not the right way for many reasons. It's not SSO, less secure, exposes authentication details as well as credentials to the applications, etc, etc..

Comment: @SubodhJoshi so you mean to say that there will be a group of users under one client and then we need to get the token for that client instead of individual users.please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Each realm may or may not contain more than one client.If you will check master realm it have more than one client by default and realm only contain more than one user/group etc info.

Answer (score 37):

You have 2 choices: you can act on behalf of some user (as *Adnan Khan* pointed out), or create a dedicated client for this.

### On behalf of the user

1) create a confidential client (I suppose you already got one)

2) create a user and assign an appropriate role/s to it: e.g. `view-users` from the `realm-management` group

3) get the token (I'm using curl and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)):

```
KCHOST=https://yourkeycloak.com
REALM=realm
CLIENT_ID=confidential-client
CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxx-yyyyyy-zzzzzzzz
UNAME=user
PASSWORD=passwd

ACCESS_TOKEN=`curl \
  -d "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" -d "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" \
  -d "username=$UNAME" -d "password=$PASSWORD" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  "$KCHOST/auth/realms/$REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token"  | jq -r '.access_token'`
```

4) finally call the Admin REST API [users endpoint](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/6.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource):

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" $KCHOST/auth/admin/realms/$REALM/users | jq
```

### On behalf of the client (Service account)

1) create a confidential client and make sure to toggle the Service Accounts Enabled setting to `On`

2) go over to the `Service account roles tab` and select the appropriate role for this client, e.g. `realm-admin` from the `realm-management` group

3) get the access token

```
KCHOST=https://yourkeycloak.com
REALM=realm
CLIENT_ID=protector-of-the-realm
CLIENT_SECRET=xxxxxxx-yyyyyyyy-zzzzzzzzz

ACCESS_TOKEN=`curl \
  -d "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" -d "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
  "$KCHOST/auth/realms/$REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token"  | jq -r '.access_token'`
```

4) call the REST API endpoint:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" $KCHOST/auth/admin/realms/$REALM/users | jq
```

> P.S. For debugging I have just written a CLI tool called [brauzie](https://github.com/maslick/brauzie) that
>   would help you fetch and analyse your JWT tokens (scopes, roles, etc.). It could
>   be used for both public and confidential clients. You could as well
>   use Postman and https://jwt.io

HTH :)

Comment: Is this changed in Keycloak 12? I can't seem to find the `Service account roles` tab?

Answer (score 2):

Users in keycloak are realm specific and not every user is allowed to access them. You will be able to get all the users through the admin API after you assign a specific role to the user in the admin dashboard. Simply do

1. In the admin dashboard, go to

> Users > myuser > Role Mappings > Client roles > realm-management

2. Assign the user any of the two roles `manage-users` or `view-users`.
3. Generate a new token.
4. Hit API with new token

and you will have your users

P.s I think you should update your question header to something more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the steps if you already have either a client and a user in a specific realm:

```bash
curl -L -X POST 'https://<idp-domain>/realms/<some-realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<client-ip>' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid api' \
--data-urlencode 'username=<username>' \
--data-urlencode 'password=<user-password>' \
--data-urlencode 'totp=<totp-if-using-mfa>'
```

Notice the last argument passed *totp*, which was not mentioned in the other answers, in case you are using **multi-factor authentication**.

or for if you have a service client:

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://<idp-domain>/realms/<some-realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<client-id>' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=<client-secret>' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=<scope>'
```

Comment: Great, but what to pass to the `<totp-if-using-mfa>` value?

Comment: @DmitriyPopov if you have 2FA (TOTP) activated, then you pass the value from your pass-code generator. If not, then you do not need to send the parameter at all.

Comment: Thank you. This is working, but not very stable — the value from your authenticator app is accepted not immediately + successive calls do not succeed. But at least sometimes I can get a token.

Comment: @DmitriyPopov I am not sure if it is not stable, otherwise Keycloak would not also work properly.