# Keycloak Account management api update password does not work

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to update my password via keycloak account management using postman and I get this error:

```
"error": "RESTEASY003650: No resource method found for POST, return 405 with Allow header"
```

My endpoint: `http://keycloak_url/auth/realms/{realm name}/account//credentials/password/`
I have done a post request

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Password reset functionality via API is removed from keycloak(12+) as it was unsafe. You can refer [this](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7393) thread from github. You won't find `/credentials/password/` api if you are using keycloak 12 or above.

Alternative that I can suggest is that use [Application Initiated Action (AIA)](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/blob/master/design/application-initiated-actions.md) or use [Admin Rest API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/12.0/rest-api/index.html#_resetpassword)

You can see further these got removed from keycloak [here](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-account-api-password-endpoint-removed-why/5274).

References : https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7393#issuecomment-773502862

Comment: as @Abhiijeet said api method is removed. but you cann still redirect your user to update-password required action.

Comment: But the problem is update password ui doesn't take current password from user for a logged in user, and updating password without verifying current password seems unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I am under keycloak 17+, I also had troubles to make it work,
The correct url to use should be like:

`https://myHost.com/auth/admin/realms/myRealm/users/99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999/reset-password`

You absolutely need the `/auth/admin/realms` keywords (some other endpoints only use `/auth/realms`) !

You will also need an access token from either a keycloak user or a keycloak client in the Authorization header. Check somewhere [else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572291/keycloak-user-validation-and-getting-token) to see how to generate and use an access token.

The body should be like:

```json
{
    "type": "password",
    "temporary": true,
    "value": "myNew-password1"
}
```

Check documentation:

[https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/17.0/rest-api/index.html#:~:text=Set%20up%20a%20new%20password%20for%20the%20user](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/17.0/rest-api/index.html#:%7E:text=Set%20up%20a%20new%20password%20for%20the%20user).